# ExtJS vbox layout autoheight

Tags: extjs4, vbox

I have two extjs items which are of variable height to be layed out vertically.

I am using Ext.container.Container for the vertical layout, using the following code.

```js
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {     
    //height:50,
    renderTo: this.renderTo,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },      
    items: [item1,item2],
     //autoHeight:true
});
```

The problem is the items are not visible on the page unless the height of the container is specified. But, the height of the embedded widgets is not static.

Is there any way to fix this issue? Any other components I can make use of which can stretch automatically to the height of the items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of height, apply a `flex` of 1 to your child elements. If you wish the ratio to be different you can play with the `flex` number. For instance, if you apply `flex: 2` and `flex: 1` you will get 2 thirds fill on the first element, and 1 third fill on the second.

For reference: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox-cfg-flex